# From root and weight lattices of SU(N) to $\theta$-functions as sections of a line bundle and $CP$-space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, projective-space, projective-module, theta-functions

I have troubles to digest the following messages/discussions in the [following work in p.10-12](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FJHEP07%282017%29088.pdf);
Which construct a map from the moduli space of flat connections $M_{\rm flat}=\mathbb{E} / {\mathfrak S}_N \to CP^{N-1}$ to the projective space explicitly.

My questions:

- What are the purposes of using the root and weight lattices of SU(N) here?
- $\theta_k$ are usually theta fuctions. But they emphasize $\theta_k$ are not functions, but sections of a line bundle $L$. Why is that?

Their discussions are detailed below:

> We now make the map $M_{\rm flat}=\mathbb{E} / {\mathfrak S}_N \to CP^{N-1}$ more explicit.
>
> We denote the root lattice of 
>   $SU(N)$ by ${\mathbb L}$
>   $$
> {\mathbb L}=\left\{ \vec{\ell} =(\ell_1, \cdots, \ell_N) \in \mathbb Z^N; \sum_i \ell_i=0 \right\}\;. 
> $$
>   The weight lattice is spanned by the fundamental weights
>   $$
> \vec{e}_k=(\overset{1}{1},\cdots,\overset{k}{1},0,\cdots,0) - \frac{k}{N}(1,\cdots,1)\;. 
> $$
>
> We define theta functions as
>   $$
> \theta_k(\vec{\phi}) :=  \sum_{ \vec{\ell} \in {\mathbb L}} e^{ \pi i \tau (\vec{\ell}+\vec{e}_k)^2+ 2\pi i (\vec{\ell}+\vec{e}_k) \cdot \vec{\phi}  } ~~~~~(k=1,\cdots,N)\;,
> $$
>   where $\vec{\phi}=(\phi_1,\cdots,\phi_N)$ and the inner product between vectors is defined as 
>   $\vec{\phi}\cdot \vec{\ell}=\sum_i \phi_i \ell_i$. 
>   These theta functions are invariant under the Weyl symmetry ${\mathfrak S}_N$ acting on $\vec{\phi}$, because each set
>   $$
> \vec{e}_k+{\mathbb L}=\{ \vec{e}_k+\vec{\ell} ; \vec{\ell} \in {\mathbb L} \}
> $$
>   is Weyl invariant, and the Weyl symmetry preserves the inner product. Furthermore, under the shift 
>   $$
> \vec{\phi} \to \vec{\phi} +\tau \vec{m} - \vec{n}~~~~~(\vec{m}, \vec{n} \in {\mathbb L}) \;,
> $$
>   they transform as
>   $$
> \theta_k(\vec{\phi} + \tau \vec{m} - \vec{n}) =e^{ -\pi i \tau \vec{m}^2-2\pi i \vec{m} \cdot \vec{\phi}}\theta_k(\vec{\phi}) \;.
> $$
>   Note that the factor $e^{ -\pi i \tau \vec{m}^2-2\pi i \vec{m} \cdot \vec{\phi}}$ is independent of $k$.
>
> We denote points of $CP^{N-1}$ by using homogeneous coordinates as $[Z_1,\cdots,Z_N]$.
>   Then, if we define 
>   $$
> \varphi (\vec{\phi}):=[\theta_1(\vec{\phi}), \cdots, \theta_N(\vec{\phi})] \;,
> $$
>   then the above properties imply that this is a well-defined map from $M_{\rm flat}$ to $CP^{N-1}$.
>
> We claim that this is an isomorphism between $M_{\rm flat}$ and $CP^{N-1}$.